# Determining the Big O of a recursive method with two recursive cases?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, big-o

I am currently struggling with computing the Big O for a recursive exponent function that takes a shortcut whenever n%2 == 0. The code is as follows:

```
public static int fasterExponent(int x, int n){
    if ( n == 0 ) return 1;
    if ( n%2 == 0 ){
        int temp = fasterExponent(x, n/2);
        return temp * temp;
    }
    return x * fasterExponent(x, --n); //3
}
```

I understand that, without the (n%2 == 0) case, this recursive exponent function would be O(n). The inclusion of the (n%2 == 0) case speeds up the execution time, but I do not know how to determine neither its complexity nor the values of its witness c.

Comment: Is this just a well-known fact that my searches failed to turn up, or how is it determined in a case like this? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The answer is O(log n).**

**Reason:** `fasterExponent(x, n/2)` this halfes the input in each step and when it reaches `0` we are done. This obviously needs log n steps.
But what about `fasterExponent(x, --n);`? We do this when the input is odd and in the next step it will be even and we fall back to the n/2 case. Let's consider the worst case that we have to do this every time we divide n by 2. Well then we do the second recursive step once for every time we do the first recursive step. So we need 2 * log n operations. That is still O(log n).
I hope my explanation helps.

Comment: Or we could say it is O(n^4). Big O is fun! O(N) is technically correct but is not a tight bound for this problem.

Comment: Damn it...I meant O(log n) all the time but for some reason I wrote O(n) oO I should go to bed...

Answer (score 3):

It's intuitive to see that at each stage you are cutting the problem size by half. For instance, to find x<sup>4</sup>, you find x<sup>2</sup>(let's call this A), and return the result as A*A. Again x<sup>2</sup> itself is found by dividing it into x and x.

Considering multiplication of two numbers as a primitive operation, you can see that the recurrence is:

```
T(N) = T(N/2) + O(1)
Solving this recurrence(using say the Master Theorem) yields:
T(N) = O(logN)
```

Comment: MartinS correctly observes that in the case where n>1 is odd, you perform 2 multiplications and more than halve the input size. Without this extra observation, the answer isn't complete or correct.